# Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group when using Cocoapods to add Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I recently attempted to add Firebase to my application. Using Cocoapods I did a

```
pod init
```

and a

```
pod install
```

here is my Podfile:

```
    # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'A' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for A
pod ‘Firebase’
end
```

And when trying to build my application I get the following error:

Apple Mach-O Linker Error Group

> Ld
>   /Users/jordanfrancis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A-dpnxkkawmymjqihivnbvuskouynh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/A.app/A
>   normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/jordanfrancis/Desktop/A
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.2
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/jordanfrancis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A-dpnxkkawmymjqihivnbvuskouynh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/jordanfrancis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A-dpnxkkawmymjqihivnbvuskouynh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/jordanfrancis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A-dpnxkkawmymjqihivnbvuskouynh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac
>   -F/Users/jordanfrancis/Desktop/A/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F/Users/jordanfrancis/Desktop/A/Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F/Users/jordanfrancis/Desktop/A/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F/Users/jordanfrancis/Desktop/A/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F/Users/jordanfrancis/Desktop/A/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -filelist /Users/jordanfrancis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A-dpnxkkawmymjqihivnbvuskouynh/Build/Intermediates/A.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/A.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=10.2
>   -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/jordanfrancis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A-dpnxkkawmymjqihivnbvuskouynh/Build/Intermediates/A.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/A_lto.o
>   -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
>   -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/jordanfrancis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A-dpnxkkawmymjqihivnbvuskouynh/Build/Intermediates/A.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/A.swiftmodule
>   -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AddressBook -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore -framework
>   FirebaseInstanceID -framework GoogleInterchangeUtilities -framework
>   GoogleSymbolUtilities -framework GoogleToolboxForMac -framework
>   StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker
>   __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/jordanfrancis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A-dpnxkkawmymjqihivnbvuskouynh/Build/Intermediates/A.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A.build/A.app.xcent
>   -framework Pods_A -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/jordanfrancis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A-dpnxkkawmymjqihivnbvuskouynh/Build/Intermediates/A.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/A.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/A_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/jordanfrancis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A-dpnxkkawmymjqihivnbvuskouynh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/A.app/A
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/jordanfrancis/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/A-dpnxkkawmymjqihivnbvuskouynh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleToolboxForMac'
>   ld: framework not found GoogleToolboxForMac clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am using Swift 3.0

Any suggestions? Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution just as I posted this question...

> You must use the .xcworkspace file after pod install instead of .xcodeproj file.

In order to do so open the location of your project in finder, then open the .xcworkspace file with Xcode (this file was create by Cocoa Pods).

Comment: What do you mean? I used "open project_name.xcworkspace" but still see this error.

Comment: This does't work for me either. @Tien Do, did you find any other response elsewhere you would like to share here?

Comment: ditto what everyone has said.

Comment: Solved my problem.! Thanks! But .xcodeproj file error will not stop me upload to app store right? and error also will not effect my project right?

Comment: And I have to use .xcworkspace  upload to itunes connect?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue with my new project, after trying many things, I finally solve my issue by updating my pods :

```
pod update
Installing Firebase 4.7.0 (was 4.1.1)
Installing FirebaseAnalytics 4.0.5 (was 4.0.3)
Installing FirebaseCore 4.0.12 (was 4.0.6)
Installing FirebaseInstanceID 2.0.7 (was 2.0.2)
Installing GoogleToolboxForMac 2.1.3 (was 2.1.1)
```

Clean your project from Xcode, also (if not sufficient) clear the Library -> Developer -> Xcode-> DerivedData folder and try to rebuild your project.

Answer (score -6):

Try this instead in terminal:

- git status
- git branch
- git add -A
- git commit -m ‘’Your comment...’’
- git push origin (Your branch name)

Comment: Git has absolutely nothing to do with asked question.

Comment: Why talking about Git in a CocoaPods issue ? O_o